# How to continue location matching in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I have set up `fastcgi_cache` on the (virtual) server. However, I want to turn off cache for the folder `wp-admin` and the file `wp-login.php`. The problem with the config is that when the folder or file is matched, it doesn't pass the request on to PHP, and NGINX serves the .php-file instead. (I have simplified the config file so it's not too big.)

```
fastcgi_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:30m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$host$uri$is_args$args";

server {
    ...

    fastcgi_cache cache;
    fastcgi_cache_valid 200 10m;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
    }

    location ~* ^/wordpress/(wp-login\.php|wp-admin) {
        fastcgi_cache off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The problem is that PHP never gets the request from `/wordpress/wp-login.php`. How can this problem be solved?

Comment: This is not necessary. Those won't be cached anyway since you are logged in and `Cache-Control` is set to prevent it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This is true. Now that I look at it, no pages are cached. This is included in `/wordpress/`: `Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0`. Must I fix this in WP?

Comment: @MichaelHampton What is it that stops NGINX from caching? The same header is sent in my dummy PHP-script which simply outputs a UNIX timestamp. Here the caching works.

Comment: Is it the `Set-Cookie` output from WP that disables the cache?

Comment: `Cache-Control` with either `private` or `no-cache` should be sufficient, unless you've somehow overridden these in your nginx configuration. I'll go look at my production site in a bit and see how I have it set up.

Comment: This is [my cache setup for WordPress](http://ur1.ca/hvdm5).

Comment: @MichaelHampton It seems WP is setting the `Expires`-header when you are logged in. However, when looking at the headers sent to the browser, the Expires is always in 1971, even though that's not what WP sends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
location ~* ^/wordpress/(wp-login\.php|wp-admin) {
    fastcgi_cache off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
         fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Without trying this, I would suppose it would work. However, this means the config will contain redundant PHP-file handling for every cache-exception location. What if I decide to add a new `fastcgi_param`? I'd have to do this to every single block.

Comment: Is this really the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: Ideally, you should only handle php when it is reasonable for an executable php script to be in the directory. Personally, I'd remove the catchall handler and explicitly spell out which php scripts can be passed on the php from /   Then in relevant subdirs, pass php only when appropriate.

Comment: No, its definitely not the only way, but it is probably the clearest/cleanest/easiest way.

Comment: What I ended up doing is moving repetitive code into a separate conf file, then including it in the necessary places. This works well and avoids repetition, but is completely counter-intuitive (that's nginx for ya).

Comment: This is not DRY enough.  The bottom block is duplicated in the other block.  Why isn't there a `continue` directive?